# Subquery returned more than 1 value. What does this mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, case

Can someone help me understand this error? What exactly am I not allowed to do here?

```
 SELECT
     CASE
         WHEN tagged_id != ' ' 
             THEN (SELECT tagged_id FROM stock) 
             ELSE ps_id 
     END AS 'Tag'
FROM
    stock
```

The full error is:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: I want to return Tagged_id, unless it's blank then I want to return ps_id instead.

ps_id is like a box/location ID and tagged_id is an item in the box.

Tagged_id is sometimes null though when the item is in it's own box.

So i want to return tagged_id unless it's blank, then i want to return ps_id

Comment: `Subquery returned more than 1 value` means that the subquery returned more than one value, and that is not allowed. Why exactly do you have a subquery, are you trying to return data from a different row? If the same row then why does it need a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `case expression` - this expression must result in a *single* value. The error message is *very clear* as to the issue.

Your *else* part returns the single value `ps_id`, and the result of your *case expression* is a column named `Tag`.

The statement `(select tagged_id from stock)` selects a column from a table, and to comply with the expected result of the *case expression*, this **must** return a single value; even if *you* know a table contained a single row (I bet it doesn't), SQL server doesn't know this until run time, however the query is evaluated to be valid in all cases at compile time. After all, returning *n* values for a single column makes no sense, and SQL Server will not allow this to be possible.

SQL Server is expecting you to explicitely return a single value, for example using an *aggregate function* or *top (1)* clause.

Do you perhaps just mean to do

```
CASE WHEN tagged_id != ' ' THEN tagged_id ELSE ps_id END AS 'Tag'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using a `case` expression was correct, but you don't need another subquery, since both these columns belong to the same row anyway:

```sql
SELECT
     CASE
         WHEN tagged_id != ' ' 
             THEN tagged_id
             ELSE ps_id 
     END AS 'Tag'
FROM
    stock
```

Answer (score 1):

This line return more than 1 records

```
THEN (SELECT tagged_id FROM stock)
```

To avoid error your query must return only one record. You can add top 1

```
THEN (SELECT top 1 tagged_id FROM stock)
```

Comment: Aside: `Top 1` is traditionally accompanied by `order by` rather than `-- Random row.`.

Comment: And since the subquery is not correlated - it will return one row from the table, and which row that is depends on how SQL Server decides to return the row.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs  when we  try using subquery that returns more than one value to the calling query. I usually Try each of the following steps.

1. If using a SQL job then launch the SQL Server Profiler to trace the
   exact location of the issue
2. Insert a TOP 1 condition on your SELECT statement --this is also
   filtering data to get unique value.
3. Try to use the WHERE clause in the SQL subquery, to filter for a unique
   value.

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN tagged_id != ' ' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 tagged_id FROM stock) 
ELSE ps_id 
END AS 'Tag'
FROM stock
```